# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input JS

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net

tengo un problema el cual tengo unas horas atorado con esto.

lo que sucede me sale el mensaje que aparece en el titulo el cual deriva de un JS que he creado, básicamente pinta una tabla, me podrian ayudar como lo puedo resolver..

```
function pintar(objConfiguracion) {

fetch(objConfiguracion.url)
    .then(res => res.json()) <<<<<<<<---Error lo marca en esa parte
    .then(res => {
        var contenido = "<table class='table'>";
        contenido += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < objConfiguracion.cabeceras.length; j++) {
            contenido += "<th>" + objConfiguracion.cabeceras[j] + "</th>"
        }

        contenido += "</tr>";
        var fila;
        var propiedadActual;
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            fila = res[i]
            contenido += "<tr>";
            for (var j = 0; j < objConfiguracion.propiedades.length; j++) {
                propiedadActual = objConfiguracion.propiedades[j]
                contenido += "<td>" + fila[propiedadActual] + "</td>";
            }
            ////contenido += "<td>" + fila.id + "</td>";  //fila["id"]
            ////contenido += "<td>" + fila.nombre + "</td>";
            ////contenido += "<td>" + fila.descripcion + "</td>";
            contenido += "</tr>";
        }
        contenido += "</table>"
        document.getElementById(objConfiguracion.id).innerHTML = contenido;
        alert(res)
    })
```

}
-------------------llamado de la tabla------------------

```
window.onload = function () {
    listarTipoHabitacion();
}

function listarTipoHabitacion() {
    pintar({
        url: "TipoHabitacion/lista", id: "divTabla",
        cabeceras: ["Id", "Nombre", "Descripcion"],
        propiedades: ["id", "nombre", "descripcion"]
    })
}
```

Este es mi controlador el cual recibe un JsonResult, el desarrollo lo estoy crando en NCAPAS.

```
 public class TipoHabitacionController : Controller
        {
            // GET: TipoHabitacion
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
            
            public JsonResult lista()
            {
                TipoHabitaconBL obj = new TipoHabitaconBL();
                return Json(obj.LisHabitacion(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Esta es la parte del BL.

```
     public class TipoHabitaconBL
        {
            public List<TipoHabitacionCLS> LisHabitacion()
            {
                TipoHabitacionDAL oTipoHabitacionDAL = new TipoHabitacionDAL();
    
                return oTipoHabitacionDAL.tipoHabitacion();
            }
    
        }
}
```

Comment: El problema esta en lo que te devuelve tu url.
Que hay dentro de `objConfiguracion.url`? Podrias añadirlo?

Comment: Fijate que tengo un controlador llamadoTipo habitacion el cual recibe de esta manera un JsonResult

public class TipoHabitacionController : Controller
    {
        // GET: TipoHabitacion
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
       
        public JsonResult lista()
        {
            TipoHabitaconBL obj = new TipoHabitaconBL();
            return Json(obj.LisHabitacion(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }